# npm: how to install the right package on naming conflicts?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I wanted to install this package: https://github.com/react-native-fellowship/react-native-navbar:

```
npm i react-native-navbar --save
```

But i've got another, outdated package from another source https://github.com/malkomalko/react-native-navbar:

```
$ npm list| grep navbar
├── react-native-navbar@1.5.0
│ ├── react-native-navbar@1.1.7 (git://github.com/malkomalko/react-native-navbar.git#fe3d9ed0c717e5304188e22f86ff63f0e029919f)
```

The first one, which i wanted to install, is a fork from the second, older one.

I already tried to update with "npm update" and i also tried to install a specific version with "npm i react-native-navbar@1.5.0", but it remains the same.

How to deal with such naming conflicts?

Comment: Uninstall it first - `npm uninstall react-native-navbar --save` - then try to install the specific version again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause. One of my [dependencies declared](https://github.com/Qwikly/react-native-router-redux/blob/master/package.json) the "wrong" package as a dependency:

"dependencies": {
    "react-native-navbar": "malkomalko/react-native-navbar",
    "react-native-tabs": "malkomalko/react-native-tabs"
  }